# Reduce Array of Object Arrays to Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reduce, arrayofarrays

```
var data=[
  {name:'Sam',ssn:123, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]},
  {name:'John',ssn:234, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]},
  {name:'Mathew',ssn:345, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]}
];
```

want to generate this to  following  format

```
[      
      {name:'Sam',ssn:123, age:25,hobbies:[{name:'cricket'}]},
      {name:'Sam',ssn:123, age:25,hobbies:[{name:'football'}]},
      {name:'John',ssn:234, age:25,hobbies:[{name:'cricket'}]},
      {name:'John',ssn:234, age:25,hobbies:[{name:'football'}]},
      {name:'Mathew',ssn:345, age:25,hobbies:[{name:'cricket'}]},
      {name:'Mathew',ssn:345, age:25,hobbies:[{name:'football'}]}
];
```

I have tried the following way. not getting any idea. I have added some basic functionality of reduce method but going forward not getting any idea to flatten it.

```
var flatten = data.reduce((curr, next) => {
  var temp = [];
  return (curr.hobbies = { name: "cricket" });
  temp.push(curr);
  return curr;
});
```

Comment: What should happen in the scenario that the input hobbies is an empty array? Following the logic of creating a separate row for each hobby this would mean removing the entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flatMap()` is the best choice here.

```js
var data=[
  {name:'Sam',ssn:123, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]},
  {name:'John',ssn:234, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]},
  {name:'Mathew',ssn:345, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]}
];

const res = data.flatMap(x => x.hobbies.map(h => ({...x, hobbies: [h]})));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data=[
  {name:'Sam',ssn:123, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]},
  {name:'John',ssn:234, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]},
  {name:'Mathew',ssn:345, age:25, hobbies:[{name:'cricket'},{name:'football'}]}
];

data = data.reduce((a, x) => [
  ...a, 
  ...x.hobbies.map(h => ({...x, hobbies: [h]}))
], []);

console.log(data);
```